# Why does certain clear plastic have an inner glow?

Tags: optics, visible-light, optical-materials

A type of plastic used in packaging for tamper resistant seals appears to have (what I can best describe as) a purplish inner glow under sunlight, and perhaps other bright light. In the image below, the glow is present but much more blue (rather, less purple) than it appears to the naked eye (most likely due to filters on the lens and the different spectral sensitivities of eyes vs. image sensors). What is this effect? (Scintillation, something else?) Why does it happen?

[image: plastic glow]

Answer (score 1):

Luminesce is the most probable answer. It is absorbing uv and radiating purple/blue.

Comment: More likely fluorescence.  If blue light is emitted strongly at the edge of the film, then it's almost certainly fluorescence.